# is 100-200 upserts and inserts in a 10 second window into a 3 node redshift cluster a realistic architecture?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-redshift, etl

Under 3 nodes using redshift we plan on doing 50-100 inserts every 10 seconds. Within that 10 second window we also will try to do the equivalent of a redshift upsert as documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-upsert.html on about 50 to 100 rows as well.

I'm basically unaware if a 10 second window is realistic or a 10 minute window... etc is good for this kind of load. Should this be a daily batch? Should I try to re-architect to get rid of upserts?

My question is essentially can redshift handle this load? I feel the upsert is happening too many times. We are using structured streaming in spark to handle all of this. If yes what type of nodes should we be using? Has anyone who has done this have a ballpark estimate? If no, what are alternative architectures?

Essentially what we're trying to do is load entity data to be joined with the events in redshift. But we want the analytics to be as near real time as possible so we want load as fast as we can.

There's probably no exact answer for this, so any explanation that can get help me perform estimations on requirements based on load will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you will achieve the performance you seek.

Running large numbers of `INSERT` statements is not an optimal way to load data into Amazon Redshift.

The best way is via running `COPY` from data stored in Amazon S3. This loads data in parallel across all nodes.

Unless you have a very real need to get data immediately into Redshift, it would be better to batch the data in S3 over a period of time (the larger the batch, the better), then load via `COPY`. This will also work well with the *Staging Table* approach to performing UPSERTS.

The best way to discover whether Redshift will handle a particular load is to try it! Spin up another cluster and try the various methods, measuring the performance each time.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using Kinesis Firehose to insert data to Redshift. It will optimize for time / load and insert accordingly.

We tried inserting manually in batches, does not seems to be the cleaner way of handling it when an optimized cloud service exist for the same.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/event-publishing-redshift-firehose-stream.html

It does collect them in batches, compress and load them to Redshift.

**Upsert Process:**

If you want an upsert this is how I would have them done in a scalable way,

DynamoDB Table (Update) --> DynamoDB Streams --> Lambda --> Firehose --> Redshift

Have a scheduled job to cleanup any duplicate records based on created_timestamp.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer will look into the firehose solution. Does this only apply to inserts? What about an upsert?

Comment: Firehose is only a insert only process. Update is a costly process. With Redshift, Upsert is a delete and Insert. Your old record will be marked as deleted until you VACUUM it. Usually we run a scheduled job to delete old records and pick up new records.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I realize that an upsert is expensive, but we may have no choice to do this... Would you happen to know if 50-100 upserts every 10 seconds is a realistic number?

Comment: I have updated the update process. Don't update records in Redshift unless it is manual. If you want it programatically, please check the upsert process mentioned.